# After submit redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have search form in php with submit button. (that made like shortcode)
I need redirect on another page with data. For example http://localhost/wordpress/?data_min=21.09.2016&data_max=22.09.2016 and with "?data_min=21.09.2016&data_max=22.09.2016" redirect to http://localhost/search_form/?data_min=21.09.2016&data_max=22.09.2016

```
$sHeader = ' <
    div class = "panel list_header" >
    <
    form class = "filter_form"
action = "" >
    <
    fieldset >
    <
    ul > ' . $sFilters . ' < /ul> <
    /fieldset> <
    div class = "filter_form_submit_button_wrapper" >
    <
    input type = "submit"
name = "submit"
value = "Suchen" >
    <
    /div> <
    /form> <
    /div>
';

return $sHeader;
}
```

How can i make this? with `onsubmit` or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$sHeader = '
            <div class="panel list_header">
                <form class="filter_form" method="get" action=" http://localhost/search_form/">
                    <fieldset>
                        <ul>' . $sFilters . '</ul>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="filter_form_submit_button_wrapper">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suchen">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        ';

        return $sHeader;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suchen" 
onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_self')" />
```

With JS, you could attach an onClick to the input!